# Django - filtering by "certain value or None"

Tags: django

I have a field in an data object that can be either null or set to some integer. I want, given an integer, to filter all the objects with that integer value OR none:

```
MyElements.objects.all().filter(value__in=[myInt, None])
```

However, this line does not work for elements with null value. More precisely:

```
MyElements.objects.all().filter(value__in=[None])
```

returns nothing. whereas

```
MyElements.objects.all().filter(value = None)
```

returns the null-valued elements.

How can I rewrite the original query (which involves myInt) correctly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [Q values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) which allow you to combine multiple clauses in Django querysets.

Your query set would be something like:

```
from django.db.models import Q
MyElements.objects.all().filter(Q(value=None) | Q(value=myInt))
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I didn't know about Q values until now.

Comment: Is there any explanation why `in` lookup not work for `None` in an iterable?

Answer (score 7):

You can try OR statement:

```
from django.db.models import Q
MyElements.objects.filter(Q(value__isnull=True) | Q(value=myInt))
```

[django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)