# Django: filtering by value in [None, other]

Tags: python, django

I have the same problem as OP in this thread: [Django - filtering by "certain value or None"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489404/django-filtering-by-certain-value-or-none):

> I have a field in an data object that can be either null or set to
>   some integer. I want, given an integer, to filter all the objects with
>   that integer value OR none:
>
> ```
> MyElements.objects.all().filter(value__in=[myInt, None]) # Query 1
> ```
>
> However, this line does not work for elements with null value. More
>   precisely:
>
> ```
> MyElements.objects.all().filter(value__in=[None]) # Query 2
> ```
>
> returns nothing. whereas
>
> ```
> MyElements.objects.all().filter(value = None) # Query 3
> ```
>
> returns the null-valued elements.
>
> How can I rewrite the original query (which involves myInt) correctly?

I am aware that OP has accepted an answer, but I would like to know **why** `Query 2` did not yield any results.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null - after all, there always needs to be a query generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is based on SQL rules for execution. NULL values are not actual values to be compared. it's an unknow value.

read more about this here: [is null vs == null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null)

In Django you can get records with NULL values like that:

```
MyElements.objects.filter(value__isnull = True)
```

So you need to first filter `None` out your list of comparisons and add it to your query by yourself.

```
from django.db.models import Q
MyElements.objects.filter(Q(value__in = [list_of_vals]) | Q(value__isnull = True))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should test if a field is null using the `isnull` filter instead; otherwise in SQL any value compared to a null value would always evaluate as false:

```
from django.db.models import Q
MyElements.objects.filter(Q(value=myInt) | Q(value__isnull=True))
```