# How to get a QuerySet with values ​of a specific field in Django while maintaining the order?

Tags: django

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)


Book.objects.bulk_create([
    Book(name='A'),
    Book(name='B'),
    Book(name='C'),
])


book_names = ['C', 'D', 'A', 'B']

some_func(book_names)
# >>> [Book(name='C'), None, Book(name='A'), Book(name='B')]
```

When I have a list of values ​​of a specific field of a model object,
is there a way to implement a function that returns the model object in the same order in the list
and returns `None` when the value does not exist?
I want to implement it using only Django ORM query without using for loop.

```py
preserved = Case(*[When(name=name, then=pos) for pos, name in enumerate(book_names)])
Book.objects.filter(name__in=book_names).order_by(preserved)
# >>> [Book(name='C'), Book(name='A'), Book(name='B')]
```

In this way, I can get list of objects in the same order,
but I don't know how to get `None` when the value doesn't exist.

Comment: Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489404/django-filtering-by-certain-value-or-none)

Comment: @Niko You seem to have misunderstood the question :(

Comment: It seems that I did. I am sorry. Personally I do not know any other way than post processing what you already have, or by using .get() method in order to validate every query using the names in the list. Either way, you are going to need a for loop.